# More efficient way to count groups of data in mysql?

Tags: mysql, select, count

I have a SELECT statement for a list of students at a school,  It currently runs with the below code, however I find it takes a good 1-2 seconds per count, most other simple queries on this database take less than half a second so I think I am doing this quite inefficiently here.  Is there a better way to do this?  1-2 seconds might not sound like much but in a more detailed statement I add to the below
to also count subjects present/absent etc so when I have everything included in the statement it is taking close to 30 seconds to run.

```
        SELECT studentID AS sID, stu.name AS Name,
        (
        SELECT COUNT( * )
        FROM attendance
        WHERE ((sID = 1)
        AND classdate < CURDATE( ))
        ) AS present, 
        (
        SELECT COUNT( * )
        FROM attendance
        WHERE ((sID != 1)
        AND classdate < CURDATE( ))
        ) AS absent
        FROM attendance
        INNER JOIN students AS stu ON attendance.studentID = stu.id
        WHERE awayid != -1
        GROUP BY sID
        ORDER BY present ASC

        ---------------------------------------------
        |   sID |   Name    |   present |   absent  |
        |   1   |   John    |   28      |   2       |
        |   2   |   Richard |   26      |   4       |
        |   3   |   Harry   |   22      |   8       |
        |   4   |   Sarah   |   22      |   8       |
        |   5   |   Tanya   |   20      |   10      |
        |   6   |   Nathan  |   20      |   10      |
        |   7   |   Kate    |   20      |   10      |
        ---------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Can you edit your query to show the structure of the attendance table?

Comment: Im just on the mobile now but will clean it up when I get bsck on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation:

```
select studentID as sID, stu.name,
       sum((sID = 1) AND classdate < CURDATE( )) as present,
       sum((sID != 1) AND classdate < CURDATE( )) as absent
FROM attendance INNER JOIN
     students AS stu
     ON attendance.studentID = stu.id
WHERE awayid != -1
GROUP BY sID
ORDER BY present ASC;
```

What confuses me, though, is the use of `sID` in the subquery.  It would not refer to the `studentId` in the outer `select`.  I suspect that another variable should be used there.  (And, if there is an `sid` in `attendance`, why are you calling `studentID` `sID` in the outer query?)

Comment: This works well. Sorry for the confusion I cut down the query to make it more readable here I will add more info to make it clearer for others

Answer (score 1):

Making a few assumptions, try this:

```
SELECT
    studentID AS sID,
    stu.name AS Name,
    sum(a.sID = 1) as present,
    sum(a.sID != 1) as absent
FROM students AS stu
JOIN attendance a ON a.studentID = stu.id
    AND classdate < CURDATE( )
WHERE awayid != -1
GROUP BY 1, 2
ORDER BY present ASC
```

Note that in mysql true is `1` and false is `0`, so `SUM(condition)` counts how many times it's true, thus avoiding the cumbersome use of `CASE` which wold be required by other databases.